# jQuery ui-effects-wrapper is chopping off the bottom of a divs content whilst using .show("slide",

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using

```
 $('#account-slide').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
```

to display a `div` when a button is clicked.

The problem is the `ui-effects-wrapper` class that is applied to the `div` when the button is clicked cuts of the `div` whilst it is moving.

Once the `div` reaches it's destination the `div` returns to it's normal state and you can see it in it's entirety.

Any ideas why the `ui-effects-wrapper` class would be causing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end I just needed to ensure everything contained within the `div` I wanted to slide was set to `height: 100%`

This is because the `ui-effects-wrapper` doesn't seem to like auto heights whilst sliding a containing div.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue where as the element would slide in and the element would be clipped on the bottom because of a height defined by jQuery directly to the animated element during the animation (in my case 28px).

There are two ways you can go about fixing this that I've found --

1. Set an explicit height to the wrapper div, then set the inner div (or element) to have a height of `height: 100% !important;`
2. Set an explicit height to the actual element, as specific as possible in the css, by doing `height: 32px !important;`

Thanks for your solution Max, mine is a bit of a refinement for my particular case based on your initial conclusion.